# Regex: last string in quotes

Tags: regex

Given this string and PowerShell 2.0

```
Jrn.Grid "Control; Modal , Opening Worksets , Dialog_Revit_Partitions; Control_Revit_Partitions", "Selection" , "Rows;Shared Views, Levels, Grids;Shared Views, Levels, Grids;"
```

I am trying to get just the last part in quotes. I started with

```
$string -match '(["])(\\?.)*?\1'
```

and while `$matches[0]` correctly returns

```
"Control; Modal , Opening Worksets , Dialog_Revit_Partitions; Control_Revit_Partitions"
```

`$matches[-1]` does not return `"Rows;Shared Views, Levels, Grids;Shared Views, Levels, Grids;"`, and oddly `$matches[1]`just returns a single double quote. 
I also tried `$string -match '(["])(\\?.)*?\1$'`, with the end of line anchor, and then $matches[0] returns everything in quotes. I suspect I am having an issue with testing for nested quotes, when in fact I don't want to treat them as nested, I want to treat them as a series.
What am I missing, to get just the last match. And, what can I do to NOT include the quotes in the capture, just what is between them?

AHA. Based on Toto's example, I added the end of line anchor and used $matches[1], thus

```
$string -match '"([^"]+?)"$'
$matches[1]
```

and it seems to be working. I'll hope I don't run into any more complicated data that breaks it again.

Comment: Why not just use: `"[^"]+"` for matching

Comment: OK, I see one issue I have. I have always thought that $matches contains each match, so $matches[0] is the first match, $matches[1] is the second, and I assumed, given PowerShell, that $matches[-1] would be the last match. Obviously not so. And, while anubhava's example returns the one thing that isn't in quotes at all, Jrn.Grid, and Toto's example returns the quoted part without the quote, it still returns the first quoted bit, not the last, Toto's pointed me in the right direct, as noted in the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
$string -match '"([^"]+?)"'
```

then the match is in `$matches[1]`